# socket.io - io.sockets.adapter object?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm experimenting with socket.io and trying to build a multi-room chat app. The guide I'm following is out of date using pre 1.0.0 socket.io.

I'm trying to find a list of connected clients in a given room. Googling around shows that I have to use the adapter. However, I cannot find the documentation for it anywhere. I searched for it in the git-hub doc but search didn't return any information on adapter. https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/blob/master/docs/API.md

Can someone point me in the right direction and where I can read more about adapter and associated methods on it? Also if you can provide the most up to date documentation for socket.io I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: maybe this will help https://www.tutorialspoint.com/socket.io/

Comment: the `sockets` tag does **NOT** refer to `socket.io`, but to a lower level network layer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get a map of all rooms in the top level namespace like this:

```
io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms
```

You can list the sockets in one of those rooms like this:

```
function getSocketsInRoom(room, namespace = '/') {
    let room = io.nsps[namespace].adapter.rooms[room];
    return room.sockets;
}
```

As best I can tell, this kind of stuff is simply not documented.  I've only discovered things like this by examining how things are stored in the debugger.  That may or may not mean it's subject to change in the future - I really have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

```
  sockets:
   { '2v8OmIS4qTGX61-YAAAC': true, '3YnScxOgpmAGhZWsAAAG': true },
  length: 2 }
```

it gives u this output.  So it basically gives you the clientId and whether it is connected or not and total number of clients connected to a specific room. When the code below is executed (in server side written in node.js) gives u the above output.There is currently two clients connected to the same room named "hello".

```
var clientsInRoom = io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room];
```

but when u write this code below and console log it

```
var clientsInRoom = io.sockets.adapter.rooms
```

when single client is connected it will console log this

```
{ '9mVAHSDwcwnqsF4aAAAA':
   Room { sockets: { '9mVAHSDwcwnqsF4aAAAA': true }, length: 1 } }
```

this crazy '9mVAHSDwcwnqsF4aAAAA' literals is client id which is unique for each client